# Increase limit of categories in SELinux

Tags: selinux

I'm using SELinux in RHEL and I see that there is a default maximum of 1024 categories.

> MCS in Red Hat Enterprise Linux supports 1024 different categories: c0 through to c1023. s0-s0:c0.c1023 is sensitivity s0 and authorized for all categories.

According to  [RHEL6 SELinux documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts).

Is there a way to increase this maximum?

Answer (score 2):

The number of categories is configured at SELinux policy build time. To change the number of MCS categories, you need rebuild the base policy and all the policy modules.

The number of categories is defined by `MCS_CATS` in the selinux-policy's Makefile. The targets and the options are documented in the [README](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/blob/rawhide/README).